# how can i get rid of: warning: value computed is not used [-Wunused-value]

Tags: c, ubuntu, geany

I'm a beginner in programming so I would like a simple answer :)

I have a for loop with multiple conditions, which prints out two arrays. It works, but i get a warning and a red line under for(). Why is it so and how can I avoid it? I'm writing it in C and I use a Geany compiler in Ubuntu. :)

```
for((i=LEN-1) && (j=1); (i>=LEN-3) && (j<=PODIUM); i-- && j++)  
{       
  printf("%d. koht: %s tulemusega %f\n", j, voist[i], tul[i]);      
}
```

Comment: you need to change `(i=LEN-1) && (j=1)` to `i=LEN-1,j=1` and `i-- && j++` to `i--,j++`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(i=LEN-1,j=1 ; (i>=LEN-3) && (j<=PODIUM); i--, j++)
```

**EDIT:**
It works because this is the correct syntax. you don't need to use and operator to combine two initializations or two increments. you can just use the `,`

Comment: this solution worked. but why does it work? can you explain? :)

Comment: The compiler was storing the boolean result in some temp variable internally , which was never used . When we remove the boolean conditions for first , last arguments of for it solves the purpose !

Answer (score 0):

This warning is because of the return value of `(i=LEN-1) && (j=1)` which is bot used further.To avoid the warning, try this

```
int temp;
... 

temp = (i=LEN-1) && (j=1);

for(; (i>=LEN-3) && (j<=PODIUM); i-- && j++)  
{  

     ....

     temp = (i=LEN-1) && (j=1);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that just adds another warning :) variable temp set but not used.